# Weird linking error

Tags: visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2005

My application is giving me a linking error when I try to build it.

```
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl _AfxInitManaged(void)" (?_AfxInitManaged@@YAHXZ) mfcs80ud.lib
```

I am building the application using Visual studio 2005. I am also linking against WINDDK for Server 2003 and Windows 6.1 SDK if this helps.

I Googled around and noticed people saying that its a precompiled header issue and it should be fixed by setting the `/Yc` switch in the `stdafx.cpp` Create/Use Precompiled header property. but that did not fix it for me and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it solved it self once I restarted my machine.. not sure what was causing it in the first place, even restarting VS and cleaning the solution a gazillion times did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Visual Studio 2010.
 `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl _AfxInitManaged`
It turned out that was from my mistake to include another stdafx.cpp in other project.
Including more than one stdafx.cpp will produce this symptom.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2005 to build a .NET 2003 solution, I encountered the described LNK2001 error.  The project did not have a stdafx.cpp file.  I added a copy of stdafx.cpp to the project and it built successfully.